# Bash script doesn't behave the same way on different .gitlab-ci

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm actually facing a strange problem with my gitlab CI !

I have 2 `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for 2 different projects (let's call them project A and project B), both of those CI configuration have a `before_script` directive containing the following code that allow me to verify the form of the commit tag if present :

```
before_script:
  - if [[ ! -z ${CI_COMMIT_TAG+x} ]];
    then
      IFS='-'
      array=($CI_COMMIT_TAG)
      ENV=${array[0]}
      VERSION=${array[1]}

      if [[ $ENV != "demo" && $ENV != "development" && $ENV != "staging" && $ENV != "production" ]];
      then
        echo "Invalid env in tag, it should be one of [development/staging/production]";
        exit 1;
      fi

      if [[ ! $VERSION =~ v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]];
      then
        echo "Invalid version tag, it should look like 'vX.X.X'";
        exit 1;
      fi

      echo set;export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$ENV;
    else
      echo unset; export CI_COMMIT_TAG=latest;
    fi
```

When the CI of the project A runs, no problem occurs, everything works as expected

**BUT**

When the CI of the project B runs, the CI failed due to a syntax error
`/bin/sh: eval: line 94: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "fi")`

It seems to be coming from the `array=($CI_COMMIT_TAG)` line but it works fine on project A

**I use the same base image for both CI**

Do you have any ideas why the CI fails only on one of the projects ? What could I do to solve this ?

Comment: Compare users, environment variables, versions, ...  The `-` before the if at the top of your code is just in here, and not in your real code right?

Comment: The `-` must be here since it is in a YAML file, this is the correct syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching for a while, I found out that because of a misunderstanding of which image gitlab ci choose to run the before_script directive, it was actually executing my script with bash in project A and with sh in project B which explains the error with project B !